# Knockoutjs disparar evento após toda modificação na UI ou no modelo

Tags: dom, eventos, knockoutjs, mvvm

Olá, como vocês fariam para interceptar mudanças na UI ou no modelo que foram feitas sensibilizando o knockout?

Usando o `subscribe`eu sei que houve mudança em uma propriedade, mas e se eu tivesse 100 modelos, com 10 propriedades cada? Queria interceptar **qualquer** mudança em **qualquer** modelo.

Tentei usar o `ko.bindingProvider.instance.preprocessNode` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) mas não tive sucesso.

Outra coisa interessante a se conseguir, no caso de usar o `ko.bindingProvider.instance.preprocessNode` é saber se é a primeira vez que o evento foi disparado, talvez adicionando um atributo ao elemento associado ao nó que é passado como parâmetro para a função.

Exemplo:

```js
function Modelo() {

  var self = this;
  self.Nome = ko.observable();
  
  self.Nome.subscribe(function() {alert('Houve mudança, mas e se eu tivesse 100 modelos, com 10 propriedades cada?');});
  
  self.mudaNome = function() { self.Nome("Novo Nome");}
}

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new Modelo());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:Nome" placeholder="Seu nome aqui" />
  <br />
  <strong>Seu nome é: <span data-bind="text:Nome"></span>
    <br />
    
    <button data-bind="click:mudaNome">Novo Nome</button>
    
</strong>
</div>
```

Alguém já fez algo parecido? Eu preciso, portanto, saber:

- Quando uma mudança no modelo está prestes a acontecer ou aconteceu, independente de propriedade, mais ou menos como eu faço usando o `subscribe` com `"beforeChange"`  e `"change"`.
- Quando uma mudança na UI (DOM) está prestes a acontecer ou aconteceu por causa de uma interação do usuário num modelo do knockout, mais ou menos como acontece com o `MutationObserver`  [(documentação aqui)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Mudanças por causa de outros frameworks não precisam ser capturadas.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o [knockout validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

Comment: @Guto Já usei o plugin mas não para esse propósito. Vou investigá-lo para ver se tenho algum insight! Obrigado!